# How to let user set his home page in c# visual studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am creating a browser and I am supposed to provide an option for the user to set his homepage. I have created a tabbed browser. Can anyone suggest me what to do?

Thank you

Comment: @Srinivas: Bookmarking is adding into fav. Home page is different, the page that you get when you click on the Home button.

Comment: Yes, I do know that. Thank you. But I didn't exactly get what you are suggesting me.

Answer (score 1):

Put a field in your configuration for the browser called UserHomePage, and be able to store a URL in it.

When the user is on a website, and uses your menu/buttons to `Set as HomePage`, store the current URL in the UserHomePage field.

When the browser is first opened, go to that URL.

If someone clicks the HOME button, go to that URL.

Comment: That was a quick response! Thank you. I got what you are saying, but not completely. Can you please show me a sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a properties window with a text box asking for user's home page url; save it somewhere accessible in future. When user click on the Home button of your browser, retrieve the url and navigate to that site.

Answer (score 0):

//declared public string "sString" 
//"Set homepage" is a tool strip. Stored textboxURL in sString. 
//Home is a tool strip button.Navigated it to sString.

public string sString;

```
    private void setHomepageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sString = urlTextBox.Text;
        string home = "http://" + sString;            
    }
```

private void homeToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {
        ((WebBrowser)tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(sString);
    }
```

Thank you "Raj More" and "KMan" for helping me.